# Shape Keys Continuous Animation

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I have researched it online, but found no answer - can I animate one mesh with Shape Keys, continuously? What I mean: I need the Key 3 to pick up shape of Key 2, change the shape of mesh, and further on. For some reason it does not work, the shape jumps back either to Key 1's or to the Basic's. I am guessing it has to do with the Relative setting in each Key- automatically it is set to Basic, and changing it to Key 2 does not work.

Please if anyone knows the answer, let me know, and in advance sorry if it is a basic question with an easy answer.

Comment: When you move to frame 1 and set the key value, you should lick on the small white dot to the right to add a key (it will turn into a white diamond and value yellow highlight), then move to another frame, value will be green and you can set and click on the open-diamond to set the next key-frame.  Etc at each frame to want changed.   Between keyed frames, the value will slowly change (interpreted values between frames).  You can go into the Amimation Graph Editor to change the Interpolation mode in the keyframe area of the panel (near the timeline cursor).

Comment: https://brandonsdrawings.com/blender-shape-keys/

Comment: @james_t hi and thank you for your prompt response; I guess I did not clearly state what I need, I know how the shape keys animation works; I need to know if it is possible to animate one shape with around 20 shape keys, when each of the keys takes shape of the previous, and not of the base key. I tried paying around with the settings of Relative, but any next key after Key 2 takes the start shape from the very beginning, and not the previous Shape Key. I will try and take some screenshots to attach, if the question is still not clear.

Comment: So I think you're asking...?... if you have Key3 Relative To Key2, how can you see the Key2 edits when working on Key3, and be able to move/edit vertices for Key3 while seeing the Key2 results?    Set Key2 value to 1 in Object Mode, then select Key3, go to EDIT mode, make Key3 *Relative To* Key2, click on the *Apply Shake Key in Edit mode* button (four cornered square on the *Relative* check box area, to the right on the *pin* button.  Ah, now I cannot edit!   Is that your problem to solve?